# Use Reactive Forms with storybook templates

Tags: angular, storybook, form-control, angular-storybook

I am developping some components and custom form elements that I want to have on Storybook.

To be complete, I want the stories to use `FormControl` and `FormGroup` to show some real use case.

I have the following story :

```
export const Dropdown: Story = {
  args: {
    label: 'Dropdown',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
  },
  render: (args) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
      formGroup: new FormGroup({
        dropdown: new FormControl("item2", Validators.required),
      }),
    },
    template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <gai-dropdown ${argsToTemplate(args)} style="width: 200px" formControlName="dropdown">
          <gai-option value="item1" label="Item 1"/>
          <gai-option value="item2" label="Item 2"/>
          <gai-option value="item3" label="Item 3"/>
          <gai-option value="item4" label="Item 4">
             <ng-template>Avec template</ng-template>
          </gai-option>
      </gai-dropdown>
    </form>
    `
  }),
};
```

And the binding does work because the component displays as follows :

[image: Dropdown]

But if I interact with the dropdown to change the value, clear it or anything, the `FormControl` doesn't change.

[image: No changes]

I am at a loss here. Everything works perfectly when using the component outside of Storybook.

In my dropdown component I register the `onChange` callback like this :

```
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeForm = fn;
  }
```

And I had declared `onChangeForm` like this : `onChangeForm: any = () => {}`.

I migrated it to a property with a getter and setter and it now works. I have no idea why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a weird interaction with Storybook Controls. The `onChange` method was overriden by Storybook controls for some reason.

Renaming the method to something random and not `onSomething` made it work. So I ended up excluding the `onChange` and `onTouched` method from the controls like this :

```
parameters: {
    controls: {
      exclude: ['onBlur', 'onChange', 'onTouched'],
    }
  },
```

EDIT: It was actually the "Actions" addon that was configured to register actions for every method starting with "on". It was configured in my `preview.js` like this `actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" }` and was responsible for overwriting my methods.